# What popular/famous games are written in C?

Tags: c, game-industry

It is very similar to this question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3789/famous-games-written-in-java

Does anyone know of any popular or famous games only written in C?

Comment: You probably already know this, but since it's related, I'll just mention that the vast majority of modern games are written in C++. It's not the same thing, of course; the languages are more different than a lot of people give them credit for. But I wanted to share that in case anyone is unaware.

Comment: @Mitch I understand that C++ is used more, just wanted to see if anyone knew any popular C games

Comment: @Mitch and yes, some game forges produce C like code using large god 'classes', few OOP and so on. Of course they use a C++ compiler, but does it really count?

Comment: -1 since, unlike the Java question, this doesn't show a lot of research.  It's almost like asking "what games use normal maps".

Comment: @Terad Well actually it's not!!!

Comment: @Tetrad It says ONLY written in C (not C/C++)

Comment: There's a period of time (mid-80s to mid-90s) where C and C/asm were the "only" option for writing games, so I'm not sure answers like "Doom" or anything for the PSX are particularly useful (although id did hang onto C longer than most other studios). More interesting would be studios today still using pure C, or Atari 2600 / early NES games written in C.

Comment: Why am I the only one that gets Downvoted? Other people have done the exact same thing as me and they got Positive votes! Why ME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doom, Quake, pretty much all id games up until id Tech 4.

Answer (score 8):

Cryptic Studios's games - City of Heroes / Villians, Star Trek Online, and Champions Online (and presumably Neverwinter Nights, but I can't vouch for that 100% since I don't work there anymore) - were written in C.

Comment: Neverwinter is definitely in C too.

Comment: Wait  were all these written in Pure C?

Comment: @Aditya: Well, and a custom interpreted language, which we wrote the interpreter for in C, and a data description language which we wrote the parser for in C, etc. Some (small) amounts of the asset pipeline were written in C++, Perl, Python, Excel macros, etc. I believe we also used a C++ shim to FMOD. But yes, for all intents and purposes the games were written in pure C.

Comment: @Joe Could you add your comments to your answer. there might be others like me who have failed to see this implied process and might imagine the entire pipleline used only c with no interpreted languages. The asset pipeline meaning the 3d? assets with bindings in pearl/python , text parsers and c++ for external libraries? I gather that you worked on these could you elaborate a bit on the asset pipeline

Comment: @Aditya: The question is closed. We don't want questions like this on the site.

Comment: @Joe i get that, thanks, my interest is in what you have to say.

Comment: Wow. That would explain some of the crazy I've been hearing about from the Titan Network folks.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of Jap/PS1/DC games. Also Soul Reaver 1, parts of Soul Reaver 2 and there was quite some plain C code in Tomb Raider: Legend.

Comment: Yep. And not only Sony/Sega consoles, even things like Super Mario 64 were written in C